# Paging3 in android how come uses inefficient offset limit pagination

Tags: android, android-room, android-paging, android-paging-3, android-paging-library

Most efficient pagination is keyset pagination as per: https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/03/30/five-ways-to-paginate/

I was curious how come paging 3 library uses the inefficient offset limit pagination and not keyset pagination or is it optimized somehow under the hood?

Comment: What makes you think that? Paging supports both.

Comment: @ianhanniballake: i couldnt find example of Paging3 using "keyset pagination" will look into it again